# Getting only the first item per state in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a table of data which consists of several items that can have different states (Submitted, In Verification, Completed, ...). The item state are not unique but I am only interested in getting the first occurence of an item per ID and Status:

| ID | Modified Date | Status | (Query should:) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01.01.2021 12:01 | Submitted |  |
| 123 | 02.01.2021 12:02 | In Verification |  |
| 123 | 02.01.2021 12:03 | In Verification | (remove) |
| 123 | 02.01.2021 12:04 | In Verification | (remove) |
| 123 | 03.01.2021 12:05 | Completed |  |
| 123 | 03.01.2021 12:06 | Completed | (remove) |
| 345 | 06.01.2021 12:07 | Submitted |  |
| 345 | 06.01.2021 12:08 | Submitted | (remove) |
| 345 | 04.01.2021 12:09 | In Verification |  |
| 345 | 04.01.2021 12:10 | In Verification | (remove) |
| 345 | 19.01.2021 18:11 | Completed |  |

I want to know when the first change happened to each state of the item. My expected result would be.

| ID | Modified Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01.01.2021 12:01 | Submitted |
| 123 | 02.01.2021 12:02 | In Verification |
| 123 | 03.01.2021 12:05 | Completed |
| 345 | 06.01.2021 12:07 | Submitted |
| 345 | 04.01.2021 12:09 | In Verification |
| 345 | 19.01.2021 18:11 | Completed |

Is there any way to get the desired result in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `GROUP BY`:

```
select ID, min(ModifiedDate) FirstModifiedDate, Status
from tablename t
group by ID, Status
order by ID, FirstModifiedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to keep the first row per ID and Status.

```
SELECT id,
       ModifiedDate,
       status
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Status ORDER BY ModifiedDate) rn
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number to rank the rows, and then pick the most recent:

```
select
*
from (
select
id,
modified_date,
status,
row_number() over (partition by id,status order by modified_date DESC) as rn
from
<your table>
) 
where 
rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
Select 
    ID, 
    Status, 
    ModifiedDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by ID,Status order by ModifiedDate) as RNUM
from 
    TableName
)
select
    ID, 
    Status, 
    ModifiedDate
from cte
where 
    RNUM = 1
```